# MAUI ListView overlapping items

Tags: .net, xaml, listview, maui, observablecollection

Currently I am trying to make a ListView work with an observablecollection<>. I have done this like 3 times in the same project, but not in the same .xaml file. I don't really know what is happening and why is it happening. All I can say is that the list I am giving to the ListView is totally fine, I have checked it multiple times via break points and writing the content into the output, so in my opinion that can't be the problem.

Here is the code of the ViewModel:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using KitchenRecipes.MyClasses;
using KitchenRecipes.Services;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace KitchenRecipes.ViewModel;
[QueryProperty("Id", "Id")]
public partial class DetailsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int id;

    [ObservableProperty]
    string title = "Nem sikerült betölteni a részleteket";  //Simple error message as default

    [ObservableProperty]
    string howToMake;

    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<Product> ingredients = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

    public DetailsViewModel()
    {
        LookForItem();
    }

    private async void LookForItem()
    {
        var ProductPages = await RecipePageService.GetProductPage() as List<Product>;

        RecipePage page = RecipePageService.GetRecipeById(Id);
        Title = page.Title;
        HowToMake = page.HowToMake;
        for(int i = 0; i < ProductPages.Count; i++)
        {
            if(page.id == ProductPages[i].idRecipePage)
            {
                Ingredients.Add(ProductPages[i]);
                Debug.WriteLine(ProductPages[i].name);
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine($"List hossza:{Ingredients.Count}");

        //Miert?
        //Product tmp = Ingredients[1];
        //Ingredients.RemoveAt(1);
        //Ingredients.Insert(1, tmp);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void OutOfStockButton(Product p)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(p.name);
    }
```

And here is the XAML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="KitchenRecipes.DetailsPage"
             Title="Részletek"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:KitchenRecipes.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:DetailsViewModel"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:KitchenRecipes.MyClasses">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="#2E4F4F"
          RowDefinitions="10*, 40*, 50*, Auto"
          Padding="5">
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
               Grid.Row="0"
               TextColor="#CBE4DE"
               BackgroundColor="#2C3333"
               Padding="2"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding HowToMake}"
               Grid.Row="1"
               TextColor="#CBE4DE"
               BackgroundColor="#2C3333"
               Padding="2"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Ingredients}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Product">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:DetailsViewModel}}, Path=OutOfStockButtonCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="20*, 5*, 7*, 2*">
                                <Label Text="{Binding name}"
                                   Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding quantity}"
                                   Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding unit}"
                                   Grid.Column="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The pathing works fine I think, cause everything is being used as it should be.

Here is the problem visually with an example:

[image]

As you can see the second Item is being overlapped with the first item. However, after the second item everything works fine.

I have tried to change the ListView to a CollectionView, but when I does that the list doesn't even show up. It exists, cause when I fill it with like 20 or 30 items the scroll bar appears, but nothing is shown.

Comment: Try check/open maui github issues for this issue. On your end you can try removing the ViewCell from the item DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the ListView into a CollectionView and the ViewCell into a SwipeView. That solved everything and it works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you provided and I removed the `TapGestureRecognizer` then it worked well. I binded the listview by using the static data. You can use the `SelectedItem` for the listviewitem instead of using the TapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: The tapgesture was added later, so the problem was present earlier. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: That might be the data binding issue. You can try to use the List with the static data to check if there has an issue on the Listview binding.

Comment: The solution was that I changed to ListView to a CollectionView and the ViewCell into a SwipeView. That solved everything it works perfectly fine now. There is something wrong with the ViewCell for sure, cause the CollectionView doesn't seem to work with it at all.